# Understanding why value is not what is expected in rails callbacks spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am writing unit tests for shopping_cart application. It contains user, order, order_item and product items.
I wrote the following spec, where the total price of purchased items is stored in `total` attribute of order: order_spec.rb

```
    describe '#total_price' do
  before(:each) do
    user = User.new(email: 'test1@example.com', password: 'test1234')
    @order = Order.new(user: user)
    @order_item = OrderItem.new(order: @order, unit_price: 100, quantity: 2,
                               total_price: 200)
  end
  it 'calculates order total price' do
    expect(@order.total).to eql(200)
  end
end
```

Order table contains the following attributes:
Order(id, total, user_id)

However on running the spec, it is giving giving error as :

```
 1) Order Instance Methods #total_price does something
 Failure/Error: expect(@order.total).to eql(900)

   expected: 900
        got: 0.0

   (compared using eql?)
```

The order model is associated with many order_items and belongs to one user.
The code for order model is as follows:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :order_items
  before_save :update_total

  def total_price
    price = order_items.collect do |order_item|
      order_item.item_unit_price * order_item.quantity
    end
    price.sum
  end

  private

  def update_total
    self[:total] = total_price
  end
end
```

Can anybody tell me why it is not saving the total?It is storing the user but not the total. What is it I a doing wrong? 
I am using rspec and capybara for testing.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lot of research, I found out that the object of order items was not getting created properly because of validations. Also I was getting bit confused in associations. But I now understood it. The correct rspec is as follows:

```
describe Order, type: :model do
  before(:each) do
    user = User.new(email: 'test1@example.com', password: 'test1234')
    @order = Order.create(user: user)
    p1 = Product.create(name: 'purse', price: 100, stock: 5)
    p2 = Product.create(name: 'shoe', price: 200, stock: 5)
    @order.order_items.create!(product: p1, quantity: 1)
    @order.order_items.create!(product: p2, quantity: 3)
    @order.save!
  end
  describe '#total_price' do
    it 'calculates order total price' do
      expect(@order.total).to eql(700)
    end
  end
end
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are experiencing one of the positives and drawbacks of callbacks, which is a level of indirection.

You set `total` but then on save your model recalculates total.  I'm guessing that you have 0 item_unit_price and/or quantity.

```
def total_price
    price = order_items.collect do |order_item|
      order_item.item_unit_price * order_item.quantity
    end
    price.sum
end
```

So to fix this, change testing that the order_items saved will end up with the total you expect.

Comment: No @austio, this is giving the same error. I have updated rspec as above, but it is still taking nil. I have updated the rspec code in the question, so that you can review it.

Comment: Cool, so there is certainly something up with the data model in this or the reference to it in your collect.  The evidence i use for that is that collect returns an array of elements and sum on an array of numbers produces a single number.  My best guess is that item_unit_price is returning 0.0 which would cause your sum to be 0.0

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Because I check through console, `order.order_items` returns all the order items present in  that order. So what exactly is returning 0?

Comment: What is value of bot `item_unit_price` and `quantity` of every item the order?

Comment: I got the solution @Austio. I have added the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving some fixed value to the total. Create order_items corresponding to the order in the spec. Then, write the spec expecting the total to be equal to the value that will be calculated as per the logic in your total price method. 
Not sure what fields you have in the order_items table, but, the code should look something like

```
describe '#total_price' do
  before(:each) do
    user = User.new(email: 'test1@example.com', password: 'test1234')
    order = Order.new(user: user)
    order_item = OrderItem.new(order: order, item_unit_price: 100, quantity: 2)
end
   it 'calculates order total' do
     expect(order.total_price).to eq(200)
   end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but it is giving the same error. Please see the edited code in rspec in the question for review .